# Prevent message deletion on iOS device

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Is there a way to prevent messages (iMessage or SMS) from getting deleted from an iOS device running version 11.2.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot prevent the user from deleting messages, if they otherwise have access to the Messages app.